# Nested if is not working as its supposed to in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

So here is the code that i came up with :-

def ab() :

```
v = raw_input (">")

if v == 3:
    print"u gotta select another one."
    y = raw_input (">")

    if y == 5:
        print"u win"

    else:
        print"you lose"

else:
    print"you lose"
```

ab()

when i type 3 it gives "you lose" instead of going in the  nested if and provide me another input option.I don't know where i messed up.Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by raw_input is of type string.

Typecast it to int like:

v = int(raw_input(">"))

or while comparing compare as

if v == '3'